# Adding image asset but the image is coming out blank

Tags: android, android-studio, android-imageview

This is what I see when I try to add an image asset in Android Studio. Normally, I remember it shows a preview of all the different sizes at the bottom. Once it is added to drawable/used in my code, it also shows it as blank. This is definitely a relatively new problem. Any ideas? Thanks!

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Agreed, I think the issue is that the action and tab icons don't allow normal image formats.

Comment: Do you want it to be an action bar or tab icon? If so, action bar and tab icons should be PNGs not JPG. You can try a free online converter and see if that works.

If you want just the image to place inside an ImageButton or ImageView add the images directly to your drawable folder(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the Icon Type from **"Action Bar and Tab Icons"** to **"Launcher Icons"** because "Action Bar and Tab Icons" will color all available pixels in your image according to the theme you choose. In your case, it was "HOLO_LIGHT" which is a gray color.

Comment: That was it. I swear it used to work with "Action Bar and Tab Icons". Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If your image is an icon, you may want to use gimp to set the background to transparent and then retry with the Icon Type from "Action Bar and Tab Icons"

Comment: Read the question carefully. What, specifically, is the question asking for? Make sure your answer provides that – or a viable alternative. The answer can be “don’t do that”, but it should also include “try this instead”. Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.